# History Browser Back is not working in one particular state

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I complete one simple project in my local machine. It have some page 5 pages. like this url

1. localhost:1111/myurlnavi/MyUrlNavi.do#Firstpage
2. localhost:1111/myurlnavi/MyUrlNavi.do#Secondpage
3. localhost:1111/myurlnavi/MyUrlNavi.do#Thirdpage
4. localhost:1111/myurlnavi/MyUrlNavi.do#Lastpage

**Code**

```
jQuery(window)
    .unbind('hashchange')
    .bind('hashchange',myOwnFunction);

function changeHash(hash){
    if(hash === ""){
        someCodes();
        pushHistoryObj("localhost:1111/myurlnavi/pages/1");     //Example
    }else{
        document.location.hash = "#"+hash;
    }
}

function myOwnFunction(){
    Some code i have written.
}

function pushHistoryObj(url,event,eventArg){ // This function - current url push to history
    var obj = {};
    obj.event = event;
    obj.eventArg = eventArg;
    if(typeof window.history.pushState === 'function'){
        history.pushState({actionObj: obj}, window.document.title, url);
    }
}
```

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeHash('Firstpage');return false;">1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeHash('Secondpage');return false;">2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeHash('Thirdpage');return false;" >3</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeHash('Lastpage');return false;">4</a>`

If i click 1 st page first going to changehash fucntion than bind function call myownFunction it all working fine. then click 2 , 3 , 4 th page its all working fine. Then i go to browser go back this also working fine.

But one new url i have like this

- localhost:1111/myurlnavi/pages/1

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeHash();return false" datadifferUrl="/myurlnavi/pages/1"> differ </a>`
Some time i click differ link it goes to changeHash() method then after that call pushHistoryObj method all case working fine but browser back is not working , If i go browser back url address bar only change pre url not ajax or changeHash method will not call ?